# tensorflow how to average several IndexedSlicesValue?

Tags: tensorflow

I defined a model of RNN in tensorflow, one of the `gradients` in `compute_gradients` is of type `IndexedSlices` while others are of type `tensor`. After I `session.run(compute_gradients ...)`, the returned value type of `IndexedSlices` is `IndexedSlicesValue`, then I have two questions:

1. How could I average several `IndexedSlicesValue` values?
2. How can I serialize a `IndexedSlicesValue` and send it to another machine through socket?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IndexedSlices is really an encoding of a sparse tensor, using a pair of dense tensors. It probably comes from the gradient of a `tf.gather` operation. There is some API documentation about IndexedSlices here that may help: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/IndexedSlices

I don't know of much code to work with IndexedSlices directly; typically they are an internal detail used as part of gradient code. Depending on the data sizes, the easiest way to work with them might be to convert them into a dense Tensor and process/send that.

Comment: Thank you very much. But how to convert it to a dense tensor? I did not find the API in tensorflow.

Comment: It's a bit awkward, but the best way I can see is to use `tf.scatter_add` to apply the IndexedSlices update to variable. I'll see if I can find a better answer for you.

Comment: `tf.convert_to_tensor` will convert it to a dense tensor.  However, it may be more efficient to just concatenate the indices and values, preserving the `IndexedSlices` structure, since the dense tensor might be much larger than the `IndexedSlices` combined.

Comment: OK, thank you very much! I will try the methods  you introduced. thanks.